# How to change text color based on a dynamic value using Angularjs directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The objective is to create a directive which can change color of the text displayed on a list based on a dynamic value.

For example, I have an array:

```
$scope.messages = [{user: "Eusthace", message: "Hello!", timestamp: 1431328718}];
```

For each user I'd like to have a different text color in the list of messages.

Comment: Please be more specific about color system and determining criteria... can be done so many different ways

Comment: The criteria is different user, different color

Comment: 500 users 500 colors? Assigned once per user or different color depending on the time of day they log in...come on...do a little bit more thinking

Comment: Exactly, 500 users, 500 colors, its what my client wants. I understand your concern, but is what I need to do... And thank you for your time. :-(

Comment: use a multiple of users array index to generate rgb or hex and apply with `ng-style`

Comment: was thinking use the user array indexing.  Every time user gets added...get index in array and generate rgb or hex as multiple of index

Comment: I'd like to create a directive to change the text color (my question is about that), can you help me with that?

Comment: Hope it will be helpful for you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8cL123/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Really helpful! Why don't you answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set css style (e.g. `color`) on an HTML element you can use `ngStyle` directive. To generate color based on dynamic value add functions to your controller:

```
var hashCode = function(str) {
    var hash = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
    }
    return hash;
};

var intToRGB = function(i){
    var c = (i & 0x00FFFFFF)
        .toString(16)
        .toUpperCase();

    return "00000".substring(0, 6 - c.length) + c;
};

$scope.generateColor = function(string) {
    return '#' + intToRGB(hashCode(string))
};
```

To use it in your view:

```
<span ng-style='{color: generateColor("dynamicValue")}'>Some Text</span>
```

example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8cL123/4/)

Comment: @Eusthace be careful by using such behavior, because you can meet situation when generated color will be similar or the same with background color.